# Why does the W3C Validator fail on this JS code?

Tags: javascript, w3c, validation

I'm trying to make a page XHTML 1.0 Transitional compliant. One of the issues the Validator has with my code lies within the following line:

```
if (isNumeric(code) && code.length == 4) {
```

Error:

> > character "&" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data

Here's another problematic line:

```
aData = data.split("&&");
```

Again, the error is this:

> > character "&" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is your javascript codes are not enclosed porperly.

Take a look here:
[Properly Using CSS and JavaScript in XHTML Documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Properly_Using_CSS_and_Javascript_in_XHTML_Documents)

Exceprt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var i = 0;

  while (++i < 10)
  {
    // ...
  }
</script>
```

VS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
  var i = 0;

  while  (++i < 10)
  {
    // ...
  }
 //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap it in CDATA:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

Javascript here

//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript code should be placed within a [CDATA declaration](http://javascript.about.com/library/blxhtml.htm) in order to pass XHTML validation.